gpt-4o retrieved context difference in langchain, it changes, but stable for gpt-4 or gpt-3.5 models


from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI

llm_s = AzureChatOpenAI(
    openai_api_version="2024-05-01-preview", 
    azure_deployment="gpt4o", 
    temperature=0,
    streaming=False, 
    #callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()],
    callback_manager=CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]),
    verbose=False,
    max_tokens=1000
)

llm2_s = AzureChatOpenAI(
    openai_api_version="2024-05-01-preview",
    azure_deployment="gpt4o", 
    temperature=0,
    streaming=False, 
    #callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()],
    callback_manager=CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]),
    verbose=False,
    max_tokens=5
)

from langchain.retrievers.document_compressors import CrossEncoderReranker
from langchain_community.cross_encoders import HuggingFaceCrossEncoder

model = HuggingFaceCrossEncoder(model_name="BAAI/bge-reranker-large")
#model = HuggingFaceCrossEncoder(model_name="cross-encoder/ms-marco-MiniLM-L-12-v2")
bge_compressor = CrossEncoderReranker(model=model, top_n=10)

bm25_retriever = BM25Retriever.from_documents(doc_chunks)
bm25_retriever.k = 10
ensemble_retriever = EnsembleRetriever(retrievers=[bm25_retriever, big_chunks_retriever], weights=[0.5,0.5])
compression_ensemble_retriever = ContextualCompressionRetriever(base_compressor=bge_compressor, base_retriever=ensemble_retriever)

memory3 = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(k=5, memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True, output_key='answer',  input_key="question")

from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

conversation_chain_sweden = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm = llm_s,
        retriever=compression_ensemble_retriever,
        memory = memory3,
        chain_type="stuff",
        combine_docs_chain_kwargs={'prompt': QA_CHAIN_PROMPT},
        condense_question_llm = llm2_s,
        #condense_question_llm = llm2_gpt35,
        #get_chat_history=lambda h :h,
        get_chat_history = _get_chat_history,
        return_generated_question=False,
        rephrase_question=False,
        return_source_documents=False,
        #verbose=False,
        verbose=True,
    )
    
def soru_sor_sweden(question):
    with get_openai_callback() as cb:
        # Ensure the response here is structured as a dictionary with an "answer" key
        try:
            response=conversation_chain_sweden.invoke({"question": question, "chat_history": memory3})["answer"]
        
        except ValueError:
            response = ("Invalid Question")
        except:
            response= ("Invalid Question")
        #print(response["answer"])
    return response





When I perform RAG in the relevant conversation chain, I have a fixed question, and when I use GPT-4 or GPT-3.5, the retrieved contexts within the prompt in debug mode contain the contexts that include the answer to my question. However, when I select the GPT-4o language model, the context containing the correct answer to the same question does not appear. In this case, the entire chain, code, and retriever remain the same; only the LLM model is changed. The context for RAG within the prompt changes when using GPT-4o.



System Info
absl-py 2.1.0
accelerate 0.29.0.dev0
adal 1.2.7
aiofiles 23.2.1
aiohttp 3.9.1
aiosignal 1.3.1
alembic 1.13.1
altair 5.2.0
annotated-types 0.6.0
antlr4-python3-runtime 4.9.3
anyio 4.3.0
appdirs 1.4.4
applicationinsights 0.11.10
argcomplete 3.2.2
asgiref 3.7.2
asttokens 2.0.5
async-timeout 4.0.3
attrs 23.2.0
audioread 3.0.1
azure-common 1.1.28
azure-core 1.29.7
azure-graphrbac 0.61.1
azure-identity 1.15.0
azure-mgmt-authorization 4.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry 10.3.0
azure-mgmt-core 1.4.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault 10.3.0
azure-mgmt-network 25.1.0
azure-mgmt-resource 23.0.1
azure-mgmt-storage 21.1.0
azure-storage-blob 12.13.0
azureml-core 1.54.0
azureml-dataprep 5.1.3
azureml-dataprep-native 41.0.0
azureml-dataprep-rslex 2.22.2
azureml-fsspec 1.3.0
azureml-inference-server-http 0.4.14
azureml-mlflow 1.54.0
backoff 2.2.1
backports.tempfile 1.0
backports.weakref 1.0.post1
bcrypt 4.1.2
beautifulsoup4 4.12.3
bitarray 2.9.2
bitsandbytes 0.43.0
boto3 1.34.107
botocore 1.34.107
bs4 0.0.2
build 1.0.3
cachetools 5.3.2
catalogue 2.0.10
certifi 2024.2.2
cffi 1.16.0
chardet 5.2.0
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
chroma-hnswlib 0.7.3
chromadb 0.4.22
click 8.1.7
cloudpickle 2.2.1
cohere 5.5.0
colbert-ai 0.2.19
colorama 0.4.6
coloredlogs 15.0.1
colorlog 6.8.2
comm 0.2.1
contextlib2 21.6.0
contourpy 1.2.0
cryptography 41.0.7
curl_cffi 0.6.0b9
cycler 0.12.1
databricks-cli 0.18.0
dataclasses-json 0.6.4
datasets 2.16.1
debugpy 1.6.7
decorator 5.1.1
Deprecated 1.2.14
dill 0.3.7
dirtyjson 1.0.8
distro 1.9.0
docker 6.1.3
docker-pycreds 0.4.0
docstring-inheritance 2.1.2
docstring-parser 0.15
docx2txt 0.8
duckduckgo_search 4.4
effdet 0.4.1
emoji 2.10.0
entrypoints 0.4
et-xmlfile 1.1.0
evaluate 0.4.1
exceptiongroup 1.2.0
executing 0.8.3
faiss-cpu 1.7.4
faiss-gpu 1.7.2
fast-pytorch-kmeans 0.2.0.1
fastapi 0.109.0
fastavro 1.9.4
fastembed 0.3.1
ffmpy 0.3.1
filelock 3.13.1
filetype 1.2.0
FlashRank 0.2.0
Flask 1.0.3
flatbuffers 23.5.26
fonttools 4.47.2
frozenlist 1.4.1
fsspec 2023.10.0
git-python 1.0.3
gitdb 4.0.11
GitPython 3.1.41
google-api-core 2.15.0
google-auth 2.27.0
google-auth-oauthlib 1.2.0
google-cloud-vision 3.7.2
googleapis-common-protos 1.62.0
gradio 4.16.0
gradio_client 0.8.1
greenlet 3.0.3
grpcio 1.64.0
grpcio-status 1.62.2
grpcio-tools 1.60.0
gunicorn 20.1.0
h11 0.14.0
h2 4.1.0
hpack 4.0.0
httpcore 1.0.4
httptools 0.6.1
httpx 0.27.0
httpx-sse 0.4.0
huggingface-hub 0.23.4
humanfriendly 10.0
hyperframe 6.0.1
idna 3.6
importlib-metadata 6.11.0
importlib-resources 6.1.1
inference-schema 1.3.0
install 1.3.5
InstructorEmbedding 1.0.1
iopath 0.1.10
ipykernel 6.28.0
ipython 8.20.0
ipywidgets 8.1.1
isodate 0.6.1
itsdangerous 1.1.0
jedi 0.18.1
jeepney 0.8.0
Jinja2 3.0.3
jiwer 2.5.2
jmespath 1.0.1
joblib 1.3.2
jsonpatch 1.33
jsonpath-python 1.0.6
jsonpickle 3.0.2
jsonpointer 2.4
jsonschema 4.21.1
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1
jupyter_client 8.6.0
jupyter_core 5.5.0
jupyterlab-widgets 3.0.9
kiwisolver 1.4.5
knack 0.11.0
kubernetes 29.0.0
langchain 0.2.6
langchain-community 0.2.6
langchain-core 0.2.10
langchain-experimental 0.0.62
langchain-huggingface 0.0.3
langchain-openai 0.1.13
langchain-text-splitters 0.2.2
langchainhub 0.1.15
langdetect 1.0.9
langgraph 0.0.21
langsmith 0.1.82
lark 1.1.9
layoutparser 0.3.4
lazy_loader 0.3
librosa 0.10.1
llama-index 0.10.36
llama-index-agent-openai 0.2.4
llama-index-cli 0.1.12
llama-index-core 0.10.36
llama-index-embeddings-azure-openai 0.1.9
llama-index-embeddings-fastembed 0.1.4
llama-index-embeddings-huggingface 0.2.0
llama-index-embeddings-instructor 0.1.3
llama-index-embeddings-openai 0.1.9
llama-index-indices-managed-llama-cloud 0.1.6
llama-index-legacy 0.9.48
llama-index-llms-azure-openai 0.1.8
llama-index-llms-openai 0.1.18
llama-index-llms-replicate 0.1.3
llama-index-multi-modal-llms-openai 0.1.5
llama-index-program-openai 0.1.6
llama-index-question-gen-openai 0.1.3
llama-index-readers-file 0.1.22
llama-index-readers-llama-parse 0.1.4
llama-index-vector-stores-qdrant 0.2.8
llama-parse 0.4.2
llamaindex-py-client 0.1.19
llvmlite 0.41.1
loguru 0.7.2
loralib 0.1.2
lxml 5.1.0
Mako 1.3.0
Markdown 3.5.2
markdown-it-py 3.0.0
MarkupSafe 2.1.4
marshmallow 3.21.1
matplotlib 3.8.2
matplotlib-inline 0.1.6
mdurl 0.1.2
mlflow 2.4.1
mlflow-skinny 2.10.0
mmh3 4.1.0
monotonic 1.6
mpmath 1.3.0
msal 1.26.0
msal-extensions 1.0.0
msg-parser 1.2.0
msgpack 1.0.7
msrest 0.7.1
msrestazure 0.6.4
multidict 6.0.5
multiprocess 0.70.15
mypy-extensions 1.0.0
ndg-httpsclient 0.5.1
neo4j 5.18.0
nest-asyncio 1.6.0
networkx 3.2.1
ninja 1.11.1.1
nltk 3.8.1
numba 0.58.1
numpy 1.26.4
nvidia-cublas-cu11 11.10.3.66
nvidia-cublas-cu12 12.1.3.1
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12 12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11 11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12 12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11 11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12 12.1.105
nvidia-cudnn-cu11 8.5.0.96
nvidia-cudnn-cu12 8.9.2.26
nvidia-cufft-cu12 11.0.2.54
nvidia-curand-cu12 10.3.2.106
nvidia-cusolver-cu12 11.4.5.107
nvidia-cusparse-cu12 12.1.0.106
nvidia-nccl-cu12 2.18.1
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12 12.3.101
nvidia-nvtx-cu12 12.1.105
oauthlib 3.2.2
olefile 0.47
omegaconf 2.3.0
onnx 1.15.0
onnxruntime 1.17.3
openai 1.35.7
opencensus 0.11.4
opencensus-context 0.1.3
opencensus-ext-azure 1.1.13
opencv-python 4.9.0.80
openpyxl 3.1.2
opentelemetry-api 1.22.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-common 1.22.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc 1.22.0
opentelemetry-instrumentation 0.43b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-asgi 0.43b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-fastapi 0.43b0
opentelemetry-proto 1.22.0
opentelemetry-sdk 1.22.0
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions 0.43b0
opentelemetry-util-http 0.43b0
orjson 3.10.0
overrides 7.7.0
packaging 23.2
pandas 2.2.1
paramiko 3.4.0
parso 0.8.3
pathspec 0.12.1
pdf2image 1.17.0
pdfminer.six 20231228
pdfplumber 0.11.0
peft 0.10.0
pexpect 4.8.0
pikepdf 8.15.1
pillow 10.3.0
pillow_heif 0.16.0
pip 24.1.1
pkginfo 1.9.6
platformdirs 3.10.0
pooch 1.8.0
portalocker 2.8.2
posthog 3.3.3
prompt-toolkit 3.0.43
proto-plus 1.23.0
protobuf 4.23.4
psutil 5.8.0
ptyprocess 0.7.0
pulsar-client 3.4.0
pure-eval 0.2.2
pyarrow 12.0.1
pyarrow-hotfix 0.6
pyasn1 0.5.1
pyasn1-modules 0.3.0
pycocotools 2.0.7
pycparser 2.21
pydantic 2.6.4
pydantic_core 2.16.3
pydub 0.25.1
Pygments 2.15.1
PyJWT 2.8.0
PyMuPDF 1.23.26
PyMuPDFb 1.23.22
PyNaCl 1.5.0
pynvml 11.5.0
pyOpenSSL 23.3.0
pypandoc 1.13
pyparsing 3.1.1
pypdf 4.1.0
pypdfium2 4.30.0
PyPika 0.48.9
pyproject_hooks 1.0.0
PySocks 1.7.1
PyStemmer 2.2.0.1
pytesseract 0.3.10
python-dateutil 2.9.0.post0
python-docx 1.1.2
python-dotenv 1.0.1
python-iso639 2024.1.2
python-magic 0.4.27
python-multipart 0.0.6
python-pptx 0.6.23
pytz 2024.1
PyYAML 6.0.1
pyzmq 25.1.2
qdrant-client 1.7.2
querystring-parser 1.2.4
RAGatouille 0.0.8.post2
rank-bm25 0.2.2
rapidfuzz 2.13.7
referencing 0.33.0
regex 2023.12.25
requests 2.31.0
requests-mock 1.12.1
requests-oauthlib 1.3.1
responses 0.18.0
rich 13.7.0
rpds-py 0.17.1
rsa 4.9
ruff 0.1.14
s3transfer 0.10.1
safetensors 0.4.2
scikit-learn 1.4.0
scipy 1.12.0
SecretStorage 3.3.3
semantic-router 0.0.43
semantic-version 2.10.0
sentence-transformers 2.7.0
sentencepiece 0.1.99
sentry-sdk 1.42.0
setproctitle 1.3.3
setuptools 68.2.2
shellingham 1.5.4
shtab 1.6.5
six 1.16.0
smmap 5.0.1
sniffio 1.3.1
snowballstemmer 2.2.0
soundfile 0.12.1
soupsieve 2.5
soxr 0.3.7
SQLAlchemy 2.0.28
sqlparse 0.4.4
srsly 2.4.8
stack-data 0.2.0
starlette 0.35.1
striprtf 0.0.26
sympy 1.12
tabulate 0.9.0
tenacity 8.2.3
tensorboard 2.15.1
tensorboard-data-server 0.7.2
threadpoolctl 3.2.0
tiktoken 0.7.0
timm 1.0.3
tokenizers 0.19.1
tomli 2.0.1
tomlkit 0.12.0
toolz 0.12.1
torch 2.1.2
torchaudio 2.1.2
torchvision 0.16.2
tornado 6.3.3
tqdm 4.66.2
traitlets 5.7.1
transformers 4.40.2
triton 2.1.0
trl 0.7.10
typer 0.9.0
types-requests 2.31.0.20240406
typing_extensions 4.10.0
typing-inspect 0.9.0
tyro 0.7.0
tzdata 2024.1
ujson 5.9.0
unsloth 2024.3
unstructured 0.14.2
unstructured-client 0.16.0
unstructured-inference 0.7.33
unstructured.pytesseract 0.3.12
urllib3 2.2.1
uvicorn 0.27.0
uvloop 0.19.0
voyager 2.0.2
wandb 0.16.4
watchfiles 0.21.0
wcwidth 0.2.5
websocket-client 1.7.0
websockets 11.0.3
Werkzeug 1.0.1
wheel 0.43.0
widgetsnbextension 4.0.9
wrapt 1.16.0
xformers 0.0.25
xlrd 2.0.1
XlsxWriter 3.2.0
xmltodict 0.13.0
xxhash 3.4.1
yarl 1.9.4
yfiles_jupyter_graphs 1.7.2
zipp 3.17.0





